# Mean and Deviation of the minimun between 2 standard distributions

Tags: normal-distribution

We have 2 standard distributions that are independent from each other and we take smallest number of the two. That should create a new distribution although not a normal one most of the times. I have done some simulation on a spreadsheet and figured some stuff like if you increase the σ, the new σ also increases or if the distributions are not overlapping then the new distribution equals the one with the smaller values. Is there a formula that calculates the new μ and σ in relation to the μ and σ of the original distributions?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "standard distributions".  Is this Gaussian $N(0,1)$ or something else? You later talk about "not overlapping" and "the $μ$ and $σ$ of the original distributions".

Comment: 2 Gaussian with an μ and a σ each. These are the 2 original ones that I am referring to. The new one is the smallest value out of the pair and it's a new distribution. When I say not overlapping, in scenarios with small σs and a big difference between the μs the smallest value always comes from one of the original distributions.